# HTTP Compression in IIS 6 - vs Third Party Solutions

Tags: iis-6, compression, gzip

Anyone had any experience with httpZip product (ISAPI - based compression for IIS). I'm wondering if this is worthwhile compared to the native compression in IIS6... Pros / Cons / pitfalls of either approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website itself tells you to use native IIS6 except for specific reasons.  If a company is telling you not to use their own product, they must have done the comparison themselves and not come out favorably.  It is refreshing for a company to actually look out for its users like that...  If you need the features, use the product, otherwise look their configuration product.

http://www.port80software.com/products/httpZip/faq#HZonIIS6